# Not able to suppress the error message using /dev/null

Tags: linux

Not sure why I am not able to suppress the error message after using /dev/null 2>&1

```
$ ll /home/harry/workbook/smoel | grep xyz > /dev/null 2>&1
ls: cannot access /home/harry/workbook/smoel: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from `ls`, not `grep`.

```
ll /home/harry/workbook/smoel 2>/dev/null | grep xyz
```